# Servicio funciona bien pero deja de responder en el instante en que la app muere (Firebase SnapshopListener)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo un app de un sitio de comidas, la app tiene una sección de "mis pedidos" que puede tener 3 estados (En curso, Aceptado, Completo). Quiero que la app envié una notificación al usuario en el momento en que el pedido cambia de estado.

Para todo estoy estoy utilizando Firebase.

El código que utilizo es este: (Funciona bien cuando la app esta viva, pero en el momento que se cierra crashea, 2 veces.)

```
public class NotificacionesReal extends Service {

private static String user;
private static DocumentReference reference;
private static FirebaseFirestore db;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ObtenerDatosUSuario();
    return START_STICKY;
}

public static void setUsuario() {
    // obtiene el usuario actual de en firebase
    user = Adress.getCurrentUser();
}

public static String Getusuario() {
    return user;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public static void SetDocumentReference() {
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    reference =  db.collection("Pedidos").document(Getusuario());
}

public  DocumentReference getDocumentReference() {
    return reference;
}

public void ObtenerDatosUSuario() {
    // tambien envia notificacion si el resto acepto el pedido
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        getDocumentReference().addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w("Error", "Se produjo un error inesperado", e);
                    return;
                }
                if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String status  = (String) documentSnapshot.get("status");
                    if (status.equals("ACEPTADO")) {
                        createNotificacion();

                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }


    public void createNotificacion() {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("idScreen", 12);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this , "a");
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Pedido")
                .setContentText("Su pedido a sido aceptado")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar, pase la ejecución del progreso "ObtenerDatosDeUsuario" bajo onCreate(), y funciono bien incluso con la aplicación sin estar en tiempo de ejecución. No estoy seguro porque ahora funciona... si onCreate() se ejecuta antes que onStartCommand.. Pero bueno, si alguien puede clarificar eso, genial.

Dejo el código como quedo por si en algún futuro alguien tiene el mismo problema que yo:

```
public class NotificacionesReal extends Service {


Context context;
FirebaseAuth Mauth;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onCreate() {
    Mauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    context = getBaseContext();
    ObtenerDatosUSuario();
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}



public void ObtenerDatosUSuario() {
    // tambien envia notificacion si el resto acepto el pedido
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    final DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("Pedidos")
            .document(Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(Mauth.getCurrentUser()).getDisplayName()));
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w("Error", "Se produjo un error inesperado", e);
                    return;
                }
                if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String status  = (String) documentSnapshot.get("status");
                    if (status!=null && status.equals("ACEPTADO")) {
                        createNotificacion();
                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }


    public void createNotificacion() {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("idScreen", 12);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context , "a");
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Pedido")
                .setContentText("Su pedido a sido aceptado")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
}
```